# Are there any stories relating Hanuman to Garuda or Vishnu or Vishnu's avataras other than Rama?

Tags: hanuman, garuda

Sri Vaishnavites call Garuda "periya tiruvadi" the big servant of the lord and Hanuman "siriya tiruvadi" or the little servant of the Lord.  Hanuman and Garuda greet visitors to Tirupati at the entrance gate.

Did Hanuman interact with any deity of the Vaishnavite pantheon except Rama?